# Checking HTML select values with Geb test

Tags: select, testing, geb

I'm trying to verify the contents of a select box with Geb. I have a solution that works but I feel like there should be a cleaner solution. Some things I've tried don't seem to work though. So this is my solution for now:

In the content part of my page I have this.

```
// language selector
langSelector { $("#lang-selector") }
langSelectorValues { $("#lang-selector option") }
```

Then to see if a language is present I'm doing something like this :

```
// check for english
langSelectorValues.filter(value: 'en')
```

I guess I was expecting a more direct way to check for the value en directly from the select element (langSelector). This way works, but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example do:

```
langSelectorFor { value -> $("#lang-selector option[value='${value}']") }
```

And use it like:

```
langSelectorFor("en")
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was looking for something more built in, but this will do.